# Mysql backup script

Tags: mysql, database, shell, scripting

I am using a script to take a backup of all my databases in the Mysql.

Script is :

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /root/Desktop/backup
echo “You are In Backup Directory”

Now=$(date +%d-%m-%Y--%H:%M:%S)

File=$Now.sql

mysqldump –u root --all-databases > $File

echo “Your Database Backup Successfully Completed”
```

But when i m trying to restore the database its giving me the following error and also there is no back at all just a file is created:

SQL query:

```
Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables]

OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databases [OPTIONS] DB1 [DB2 DB3...]

OR     mysqldump [OPTIONS] --all-databases [OPTIONS]

For more options, use mysqldump --help
```

MySQL said: Documentation

`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Usage: mysqldump [OPTIONS] database [tables] OR mysqldump [OPTIONS] --databa' at line 1`

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got it, i need to define password in `my.cnf` so it automatically used or i have to define it in the command i am executing in the script `mysqldump -u root -p 'password' --all-databases > $File.`

Thanks for your efforts guys.

Comment: But still when i m importing it with phpmyadmin,the import command is exectued succuesfully but there is not database tables there in the mysql.Still stucked around.

Answer (score 0):

you will get 1064 error if your delimiter is not properly used or keyword with any argument,check your backup file and try to run that sql command in sqlyog,you can figure out where is the mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash 
cd /root/Desktop/backup 
echo "You are In Backup Directory"

Now=$(date +%d-%m-%Y--%H:%M:%S)
File=$Now.sql
mysqldump -uroot -p --all-databases > $File

echo "Your Database Backup Successfully Completed"
```

You were getting the issue because of "-" it was some other character in your script in mysqldump statement.

Comment: there must be space in between "mysqldump -uroot"